# Knockout Validation skipping a property

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using the Knockout Validation plugin (https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) to validate my view model but have run

into an issue with properties that have been dynamically added to the view model. They basically get ignored when you call is valid on the

view model.

```
var myViewModel = ko.validatedObservable({
    property1: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
    property2: ko.observable().extend({ max: 10 })
});

myViewModel()["property3"] = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

console.log(myViewModel.isValid()); //false

myViewModel().property1('something');
myViewModel().property2(9);

console.log(myViewModel().property3.isValid()); //false
console.log(myViewModel.isValid()); //true
```

The above code creates a model with 2 properties and then add a third. Calling isValid on the 3rd property returns false, but when you call

isValid on the model it seems to ignore the 3rd property and returns true.

Any ideas how I can extend a model and the validation still work?

Comment: This scenario is not really supported by the plugin... what you can do is to rerun the `ko.validatedObservable` after adding the new properties: `myViewModel()["property3"] = ko.observable().extend({ required: true }); myViewModel = ko.validatedObservable(myViewModel())`

Answer (score 1):

When you use ko.validatedObservable, the library will walk through your viewModel and make each property using validation a dependency to isValid. Because your property is added after, it is not added as a dependency to the validatedObservable isValid flag.

What you can instead use is the group functionality to delay the creation of the isValid function. (https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validating-Only-Specific-Observables)

Example

```
var myViewModel = {
    property1: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
    property2: ko.observable().extend({ max: 10 })
};

myViewModel()["property3"] = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
ko.validation.group(myViewModel());

console.log(myViewModel().isValid());
```

The above code will create a grouping of all validatable observables in your view model. It will create the isValid function on the view model as well.

Here is a link to the source of the function so you can better understand what it's doing: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Src/api.js#L132